# python script that receives the input of a push button on Raspberry Pi 1 using GPIO pins, communicates to Raspberry #2 Pi via IP, and turns on an LED

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a create a python scripting scripting in which Raspberry A accepts the input and communicates the user input to Raspberry B through IP ADDRESS and turns on the LED

Comment: That's fine. And your question is?

Comment: I am a new bee. I am learning. How to write the code for it? I know how to do it individually but I dont know how to connect all the program together. If you could provide me a complete code, I can learn and see where my mistakes are.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do all those in Python running on Raspberry Pi.

For push button input, you can use RPi.GPIO which is Python module for accessing Raspberry's GPIO. You can check the website :
https://pypi.org/project/RPi.GPIO/

And then, for communicating between 2 Raspberry Pis via IP based protocol, you can use MQTT. Check the website first to get to know what MQTT is :
http://mqtt.org/

So, in MQTT, we have `Broker`, `Subscriber`, and `Publisher`. One of your Raspberry has to be `Publisher`, and the other one has to be `Subscriber`.

Just let's say, Raspberry #1 is the one which sends input of push button. And Raspberry #2 is the one which receives from Raspberry #1 and then turns on LED. So, Raspberry #1 should be `Publisher`. And Raspberry #2 should be `Subscriber`

For the `Broker`, you can use online `Broker` or if your Raspberry Pis are working offline, you can manage your Raspberry #2 as `Broker`. You can do that by using `mosquitto`. See the website :
https://mosquitto.org/

And for all those MQTT things above, you can do all of that in Python. Check this website :
https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/

That's it. I can assure you this will work. Because I have been doing this before. So, let me know if you have any problem.

**Edited 2019-08-13**

So, I assume you are already successful in reading input from a push button and turning on LED in Raspberry Pi. The, here is what you're gonna do :

- In Raspberry Pi #2, install `mosquitto` from terminal.

> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install mosquitto
> ```

- Reboot your Raspberry Pi #2. Mosquitto service should start automatically after reboot.
- In both Raspberry Pi #1 and #2, install `paho-mqtt`.

> `pip install paho-mqtt`

- After that, you can start coding a simple `Publisher` and `Subscriber`. You can look at this tutorial for instance :
  http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/into-mqtt-python-client/
- Don't forget to change the broker address to your Raspberry Pi #2 IP address.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Darmaji. I have never used Raspberry Pi before, So I don't know how to start how to connect with each other. I can do individually the points like switch button then individually the client and server. How should I make those transitions directly?

Comment: I'm gonna edit my answer and add step by step installation you need to do.